# serialize and deserialize enum with Gson

Tags: java, serialization, enums, deserialization, gson

How can i serialize and deserialize a simple enum like this  with gson 2.2.4 ?

```
public enum Color {

    RED, BLUE, YELLOW;
}
```

Comment: why this question is closed? I mean, related question only about parsing, not about serializing

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to [**Gson API documentation**](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0/com/google/gson/Gson.html), Gson provides default serialization/deserialization of `Enum`, so basically it should be serialized and deserialized using the standard `toJson` and `fromJson` methods, as with any other type.

Comment: by default, Gson serializes and deserializes by using the name of the enum instead of the ordinal value. Is there a way to set up one serializer and deserializer to handle all Enums by their ordinal values?

Comment: You can add annotation `@SerializedName` for enum.

Comment: @ViliusK that will make my enum to serialize as a String.valueOf(ordinal), is there a similar annotation or way to make my serialized enum an int? e.g. "color" : 1 is what I want, not "color" : "1". (mind the double quotations around 1)

Comment: the link is dead.

Comment: @SerializedName produces a string and not an integer.

Answer (score 212):

You can try this.

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public enum Color {

    @SerializedName("0")
    RED (0), 

    @SerializedName("1")
    BLUE (1),

    @SerializedName("2")
    YELLOW (2);

    private final int value;
    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private Color(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: this does not work with older versions of GSON. It works with version 2.1 and greater.

Comment: He asked for version 2.2.4, so yes

Comment: This is a really great approach. I use it often, and I think that in newer versions of GSON, users should lean toward using this approach because it's concise and doesn't require complex custom serialization/deserialization code.

Comment: How to desalinize an unknown value of enum to `Unknown`? For example the above enum `Color` should have an `Unknown` field which represent value which is none of `0`, `1` or `2`.

Comment: Will this work both if I choose to pass strings ("0","1"..) and if I pass numbers? (0,1,2..)?

Comment: This blog post helped me: Simple deserialization of Java enums using Google GSON annotations http://blog.jensdriller.com/simple-deserialization-of-java-enums-using-google-gson-annotations/

Comment: I have a restful web service that handles enum value (1, 2) instead of name when communicating, so the service is unable to parse the string value ("COLOR") in the request. The response object obtained from service is deserialized just OK with the numeric value. So this approach helped a lot.

Comment: this works in a debug build but not with a release build apk. It crashes saying: "java.lang.NoSuchFieldException" [YOUR_ENUM_NAME_HERE]. Any ideas?

Comment: Found my issue. My proguard needed to keep my enum classes. See here:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543607/assertionerror-in-gson-enumtypeadapter-when-using-proguard-obfuscation

Comment: This produces string values and not integers.

Comment: What if they API could send empty and/or null value too? How can we handle that? is it correct: `@SerializedName("") UNKNOWN("")`?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine as well, don't know from which version of GSON though:

```
public enum OrderLineTimeRegistrationStatus {
    None(0), Started(1), Paused(2);

    private int value;

    private OrderLineTimeRegistrationStatus(int value)
    {
        this.value=value;
    }

    public int getValue()
    {
        return(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am afraid, it does not work. Using Gson 2.8.0. How it could work anyway? Gson is smart, but not that smart.