# Parse Json with Gson in EnumClass

Tags: java, android, json, enums, gson

[image: I have like this json]

I have like this json.I'm using Gson to parse it and convert it in my custom class object.Here is a my java classes

```java
public class ResponseModel {
    private int resultCode;
    private Match match;

    public Match getMatch() {
        return match;
    }
    public int getResultCode() {
        return resultCode;

    }
}

public class Match {

    private Team team1;
    private Team team2;

    private double matchTime;

    public Team getTeam1() {
        return team1;
    }

    public Team getTeam2() {
        return team2;
    }

  private Long matchDate;
    private String stadiumAdress;

    public double getMatchTime() {
        return matchTime;
    }

    public Long getMatchDate() {
        return matchDate;
    }

    public String getStadiumAdress() {
        return stadiumAdress;
    }
}

public class Team {
    private String teamName;
    private String teamImage;

    public String getTeamName() {
        return teamName;
    }

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public String getTeamImage() {
        return teamImage;
    }

    public void setTeamImage(String teamImage) {
        this.teamImage = teamImage;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public int getBallPosition() {
        return ballPosition;
    }

    public void setBallPosition(int ballPosition) {
        this.ballPosition = ballPosition;
    }

    private int score;
    private int ballPosition;
}
```

I'm using Gson like this

```
ResponseModel responseModel = GsonUtil.fromJson(response.toString(), ResponseModel.class);

public class GsonUtil {

    public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> c) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(json, c);
    }

    public static String toJson(Object c) {
        return new Gson().toJson(c);
    }

}
```

Everything working perfect,I can convert my json to custom class.But I want to use enum class with team1 and team2. My goal is to convert like this enum class

```
MatchTeamType:
TEAM1 (1);
TEAM2 (2);
```

How I can rewrite my code with enum class?
Thanks

Comment: Depending on the version of Gson you are using, you could use the`SerializedName` annotation. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740078/serialize-and-deserialize-enum-with-gson).

Comment: What exactly is `MatchTeamType`? Is it the team name or something inferred from the Json only known to your domain?

Comment: it’s not clear to me what you’re trying to do