# NoSuchMethodException on Firebase.setAndroidContext()

Tags: java, android, firebase

My application is isn't able to start. `Firebase.setAndroidContext()` in my `onCreate()` method is causing a NoSuchMethodException. See below:

```
protected Firebase ref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String firebaseUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_url);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());
    ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);

}
```

I also setup an application:

```
public class FirebaseApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

Which leads to the following stacktrace from logcat:

```
I/sf_frame_dur(   60): [com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher,0,0,0,20,42,40,20]
D/AndroidRuntime(14165): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(14165): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14165): Process: com.github.r351574nc3.earshot, PID: 14165
E/AndroidRuntime(14165): java.lang.AssertionError: impossible
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:35)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstants(Class.java:1029)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.collectFeatureDefaults(MapperConfig.java:73)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfigBase.<clinit>(MapperConfigBase.java:28)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:433)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:364)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.firebase.client.Firebase.<clinit>(Firebase.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setAndroidContext(Firebase.java:860) 
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.github.r351574nc3.earshot.EarshotApplication.onCreate(EarshotApplication.java:11)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1008)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4397)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:143)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: values []
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:41)
E/AndroidRuntime(14165):    ... 22 more
```

From the stacktrace, you can see that the code that is actually causing the crash is `Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());`

Am I doing something wrong here? This is what the examples use, so I'm kinda confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in Firebase API docs, the Firebase should be initialized before any Firebase reference is created or used. You should use `setAndroidContext` method in **Application's** `onCreate()` method. So you should create your own application class like this:

```
public class FirebaseApplication extends android.app.Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    }
}
```

Then add it as name of your `application` tag in `AndroidManifest`:

```
 <application
        android:name="your.package.name.FirebaseApplication"
        //android:icon, android:label, android:theme, etc.
        ... >
      ...
  </application>
```

And then you can use `Firebase` in your activities:

```
protected Firebase ref;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String firebaseUrl = getResources().getString(R.string.firebase_url);
    ref = new Firebase(firebaseUrl);

}
```

**EDIT:**

So I don't know what's your problem, cause I was able to successfully build the project with Firebase, as in example. But I found one thing, that may be helpful for you. Try to add next lines to the `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: I see. I was initializing Firebase in my Activity when I should have done it in the Application. Thanks.

Comment: This ended up not working for me. The problem is that `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);` is triggering a NoSuchMethodException. I made edits to my problem above. Observe and see if I did it correctly.

Comment: Did you remove `Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());` from your `MainActivity` ?

Comment: I did remove it. I made the changes to my original question to reflect what it currently is. However, according to the Firebase docs it can be in your Activity or in your Application.

Comment: Yes, it can be in the Activity, but **before any reference is created**. So, can you update your logcat with new exception, that appears when you move `setAndroidContext` to the Application? Because I can see that it's your old Log.

Comment: Yes, `Firebase.setAndroidContext` is the first thing that gets called for Firebase. I updated the stacktrace. This is pretty much straight out of an example project BTW. I figure it must be something I'm missing like a resource or a dependency or something. I am using android-20 with firebase client 2.0.0

Comment: Proguard change worked for me. Linking in another issue for more background: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20651575/android-release-apk-crash-with-java-lang-assertionerror-impossible-in-java-lang