# Android Studio Signed APK - Works from one PC, fails on the other

Tags: android, apk, proguard, signing

I have always built signed APK from my current laptop with no problem. However, the last signed APK was built from another PC and every signed apk from my PC now works but crashes using "assertionError: impossible" being thrown by different libraries I'm using in the application.

Now, whenever I build a signed apk, it crashes when opening the app. However, when it's built on the other PC, it works perfectly. We're both using V1/V2 signing and the release version of the app.

We are using git and the other PC is just pulling, so there is no code difference between the 2 machines. The only difference might be the configuartion, however, we're using the same ones when signing an APK.

Please note that the proguard rules are working fine when the app is signed from the other machine but it seems they are being ignored (maybe) when building from my machine, even though I'm using the correct flavor and build type and that this only started to happen when the other machine signed an APK, without any code changes.

EDIT: Here's an example of the stack trace of the crashes I'm getting:
(Please note that the crashes are not always from glide. Sometimes quickblox, sometimes even the support library would throw this exception)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: impossible
       at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:45)
       at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:36)
       at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:54)
       at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:211)
       at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:48)
       at java.util.EnumSet.of(EnumSet.java:152)
       at java.util.EnumSet.of(EnumSet.java:172)
       at java.util.EnumSet.of(EnumSet.java:194)
       at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler.(Downsampler.java)
       at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.StreamBitmapDecoder.(StreamBitmapDecoder.java)
       at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.StreamBitmapDataLoadProvider.(StreamBitmapDataLoadProvider.java)
       at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.(Glide.java)
       at com.bumptech.glide.GlideBuilder.createGlide(GlideBuilder.java:203)
       at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.get(Glide.java:155)
       at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.(RequestManager.java)
       at com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager.(RequestManager.java)
       at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.supportFragmentGet(RequestManagerRetriever.java:198)
       at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:104)
       at com.bumptech.glide.manager.RequestManagerRetriever.get(RequestManagerRetriever.java:87)
       at com.bumptech.glide.Glide.with(Glide.java:629)
```

Comment: What is the output of logcat? If you app crashes, you should see a stack trace.

Comment: post logcat for better understanding

Comment: @ParthBhoiwala Yes, I mentioned in the post that the crashes were "assertionError: impossible" being thrown from multiple libraries, sometimes glide, sometimes quickblox, both which I have proguard rules for and working if I sign from the other machine. They don't work if I sign from my current machine.

Comment: different certificates while signing?

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20651744/6267116

Comment: @ParthBhoiwala Thank you for the help, yes I have. No difference.

Comment: @DivyeshPatel I have edited my post. Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20651744/6756514

Comment: @Opiatefuchs no, i's the same certificate because we were able to upload the version to the store.

Comment: Try doing a clean build. `Build->Clean` and `Build->Rebuild`. If that doesn't work, can you generate a new certificate/new key and a new signed apk?

Comment: Clean didn't work. I have tried that. I will try the other option.

Comment: any solutions???

Comment: @AhmadShahwaiz Solution I believe was updating the version of android studio used -> recloning the repo and making sure all proguard rules were met.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `compileOptions` under `android` inside the app-level build.gradle with source compatibility to JAVA 8.

This solved the issue for me. I had JAVA 11 installed on my machine and was getting the same above error but adding the `compileOptions` solved the issue.

```
android {

    compileSdkVersion...
    ...

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```